# Is there any way to release all SVN references after checking out the project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn

We are using SVN repository. Please note this is the 1st time I am using it and I have used TFS before.

To get latest code from SVN we do a checkout on the project folder.
After that there is a green checkmark on the locally downloaded folder.

When we try to open a visual studio solution from this folder, we get error loading project due to SVN references. Is there anyway to release the SVN checkout lock or something?

Comment: I have got this error resolved in another way:- by deleting the SVN reference lines from the Project file by opening it in notepad...

Comment: But my solution has 15 projects is there any way to do this for all of them together

Comment: There must be someway to release the checkout lock.. Lets see what others answer

Comment: What is the actual error message that you're getting? Have you installed AnkhSVN? It hooks into Visual Studio and may resolve some of your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this by deleting the SVN reference lines from the Project file by opening it in notepad